# Show custom form tied to custom record type in Customization menu

Tags: netsuite

I created a custom record type to track maintenance line items about our customers. This is my first foray in custom record types. The custom form was generated and I want to edit it. Currently for me to edit my custom form, I must go to the custom record type, click on the forms subtab and edit from there. Is there a way to get the new custom form to show up in the Customization > Forms > ... menu somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

easiest way to do this is by creating a shortcut on your shortcut portlet.
Just copy the form's URL and create the shortcut.
Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 0):

Go to your custom record and in the forms subtab, make your custom form 'Preferred'. Go to permission subtab, choose your role and choose the default form as the custom form and Restrict form to checked.